# LaTeX Error: Missing \begin document

Tags: errors

While I was working on my document after adding some lines of regular text and I tried to compile it to see how it looks like. Suddenly it stopped compiling properly and give me an error `!LaTeX Error: Missing \begin document` and when I skip all the warning it gives me a pdf with only the equations, without text.
I already tried some hints that I found in the forum and it is already encoded in utf-8. Also I asked a friend if he can help me and he told me that it did not compile properly to his computer either but he managed to obtain a proper pdf. But when I tried from a different compilers(online and not) I couldn't get the correct pdf.   `

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{shadow}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{svrsymbols}
% 
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{hyperref}


%
%\setmarginsrb{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}
% 
\definecolor{jd_blue0}{rgb}{0.51,0.34,1.00}
\definecolor{jdbishop}{rgb}{0.27,0.14,0.29}
\definecolor{jddarkbl}{rgb}{0.18,0.14,0.29}
\definecolor{jd_brown}{rgb}{0.29,0.14,0.14}
\definecolor{jd_green}{rgb}{0.00,0.14,0.14}
\definecolor{jdorange}{rgb}{1.00,0.55,0.00}
\definecolor{jdredred}{rgb}{0.50,0.00,0.00}
% 
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}         %space between paragraphs 
\setlength{\parindent}{0.7cm}       %shift into the right at the beginning of P.
%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.05cm}       %line thickness for the frames 
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.20cm}        %spacing between frames and formulae

\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5cm} 
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2.5cm} 
\addtolength{\textheight}{2.0cm} 
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.5cm} 

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.90}

%\pagestyle{empty} 
%\pagestyle{plain}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{Name, "Title"} 

\setcounter{chapter}{0}             % to start with the chapter no 1 
\setcounter{page}{1}                % to start with the page number 
\setcounter{figure}{0}              % to start the numbering of figures 

\def\ds{\displaystyle} 
\def\sty{\scriptstyle} 
\def\Vec{\overrightarrow} 
\def\vep{\varepsilon}

\def\E{    {\mathcal{E}}} 
\def\F{    {\mathcal{F}}} 
\def\H{\hat{\mathcal{H}}} 
\def\M{\hat{\mathcal{M}}} 
\def\N{\hat{\mathcal{N}}} 
\def\P{\hat{\mathcal{P}}}
\def\R{    {\mathcal{R}}}
\def\T{\hat{\mathcal{T}}}
\def\K{\hat{\mathcal{K}}}

\def\U{\hat{U}}

\def\ap{{\hat{a}}^{\,+}} 
\def\am{{\hat{a}}^{\, }} 

\def\etap{{\hat{\eta}}^{\,+}} 
\def\etam{{\hat{\eta}}^{\, }} 

\def\be{\boldmath\begin{equation}}
\def\ee{\end{equation}\unboldmath}

\def\beq{\boldmath\begin{eqnarray}}
\def\eeq{\end{eqnarray}\unboldmath}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

...
```

This is all the code I have between the beginning and the `\begin{document}`. I also tried to move the packages inside the document but it didn't work.
Thank you.

Edit:
Here is the .log document

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2018.10.13)  7 MAY 2020 21:08
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Template.tex
(./Template.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1  .
      ..
? 
! Interruption.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \endgroup 
l.1  .
      ..
? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5 strings out of 492983
 138 string characters out of 6134921
 53951 words of memory out of 5000000
 3671 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5i,0n,4p,21b,14s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeXSX! No problem here with the posted, after  I've completed it with `\end{document}` and commanded the loading of packages I don't have. Usually, this error comes from a mistyping in the preamble.

Comment: After the `Missing \begin document`, a few lines later you will see `l.#` (a lower case L, and ., and then a number) and then some text.  That indicates the line number where TeX is running into problems, and the problematic text.  You can also try deleting your aux file.

Comment: most likely you need to delete your `.aux` file, but you have not shown the error log so hard to be sure. Unrelated but don't load `epsfig` unless you need to emulate a syntax used in the  1980s.

Comment: Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1  .
      ..
That's what I get after {Missing \begin document} and I already deleted the .aux document

Comment: \oddsidemargin must be larger than -1in (possibly equal to).  The blanks in \def\E{   {... are not ignored.

Comment: You said your file is encoded in utf-8. Is it possible that there is an invisible Unicode character in your file (specifically in the first line)?

Comment: That was it !!! Thank you sincerely.

Comment: I suspect the first character would be a BOM - byte order mark, inserted by some editor surreptitiously, and not visible in various editors.